# C++ place char in corresponding slot in array

Tags: c++

I need to store a letter a-z char to its corresponding slot  in a size 0 - 25 array in c++. What's the best way to do this without a lot of if statements?

Comment: `char c; cin >> c; int x = c - 'a';`

Comment: @David Hammen No, I don't have my book with me and stackoverflow is faster than google. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can determine character index the following way:

```
int index = yourCharacter-'a';
```

And then use that index to store what you need

Comment: This assumes that 'a' to 'z' are numbered consecutively. This is true on almost all computers nowadays because ASCII won out over EBCDIC. There are still some computers around whose locale is EBCDIC, and this trick won't work there.

Comment: Can you also tell me how I can get from int to char?  And what would be a good C++ syntax book?

Comment: To get your char back from index? char c = index + 'a';

Answer (score 2):

To work out the index just subtract **'a'** from a char variable that holds the characters a-z. For example:

```
char c='x';
int index=(int)(c-'a');
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what are you looking for?

```
char c;
...
arrayName[c - 'a'] = value;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**
Not homework, so I'll clarify my answer.

`const char * letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`

Stores the letters from 'a' to 'z' in in an array. (Note that the array size is 27, not 26, because of the null character at the end of the string.)

Comment: provided the level of C++ knowledge that clearly shows in the OP you should provide much more details, at least `char a[] = "abc...xyz";`, and also to elaborate on your second line

Comment: I intentionally answered a bit vaguely because this looks very much like homework to me. When it comes to homework, a hint is better than a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Characters are just integers, so you can do arithmetic on them.

```
char c = ...;
array[c - 'a'] = c.
```

Note that upper case characters are distinct from lower case ones, so you'll need to handle them separately (if required).

```
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
    c += 'a' - 'A'; // make lower case
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be portable, you can't use the solution proposed by most
others: `'a'` to `'z'` are not necessarily contiguous.  The surest
solution is to look the letter up in a table, and use the index of that
table, e.g.:

```
char letters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

int index = std::find( begin( letters ), end( letters ) - 1, ch )
        - begin( letters );
if ( index < size( letters ) - 1 )
    //  it's good
else
    //  character wasn't a (lower case) letter.
```

Note the `- 1` for `end` and `size`: this is because `letters` has an
additional `'\0'` at the end.

Note that in a lot of cases, on a modern machine, it may be just simpler
to use an array of 256 entries; the difference in space isn't likely to
cause you to run out of memory, and the code to manage it will be a lot
simpler.

Comment: @AProgrammer Definitely.  Just an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

```
char letters[26];

for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
{
    letters[c - 'a'] = c;
}
```

Comment: There are 26 letters in the alphabet, not 25. Your array only has place for 25 elements.